# Can I use NDepend to count casts?

Tags: c#, ndepend

I've got some inherited code that has a tendency to pass objects around as interfaces (IFoo, for example) then, at arbitrary places in the code, spontaneously cast them to concrete implementations of those interfaces (say, MyConcreteFoo).

Here's a silly example:

```
public bool IsThisFooScaredOfMonkeys(IFoo foo)
{
    if (foo is MyConcreteFoo)
    {
        return ((MyConcreteFoo)foo).BelievesMonkeysAreEvil;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I'd like to do is write an NDepend CQL query to pick up these sorts of casts and give me a count per method, or per type, or anything really.  Just something so I know where I can start focusing my efforts on getting rid of this particular brand of silliness, rather than sending my team spelunking through the code on a random hunt for casts...

Does anyone know if there's a way to do that?  I'm guessing not (there can't be too many people out there who need that particular functionality) but I figured I'd ask here first... :-)

Of course, any other ideas on ways to make the cast-hunting go faster would be equally appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be very nice, but [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is limited to a set of entities which does not cover individual statements.

[NDepend Entities](http://www.ndepend.com/CQL.htm#_Toc225920007)

1. Methods
2. Fields
3. Types
4. Namespaces
5. Assemblies

Despite this limitation NDepend is still pretty awesome! Perhaps this is a version next feature.

Now Patrick Smacchia might be able to tell me different, so I would contact him with this question. I would expect to get a response back quickly as he is pretty on top of things.

### On A Side Note:

If you are using [ReSharper 5.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) it has a [Structural Search](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/) that would allow you to find statements like this. You would have to build the search yourself, but it is a pretty powerful tool.

This pattern would catch the example above:

```
if($fooObject$ is $concreteFoo$)
{
    return (($concreteFoo$)$fooObject$).$anyIdentifier$;
}
```

Comment: I do indeed have ReSharper 5.0, and the structural search link gave me my answer.  For anyone else who's curious, I set up a couple searches, one for finding "is" and one for finding "as" (there's probably a way to combine them, but this works for me).

Search text is "$foo$ as $fooClass$", then add a placeholder of type Expression for "foo" that is of type IFoo or derived type, and a placeholder of type Type for "fooClass" that is also of type IFoo or derived type.  Voila, I've got a list of all the places we cast.

Thanks Josh, this is going to make my life a lot easier!